# Does every 2-dimensional subset of the plane contain an open set?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

My question (in the title) is for (a) compact spaces and also (b) for non-compact spaces.

Regarding (a), all of the compact 1-dimensional subspaces of the plane seem to be nowhere dense (contain no open set). But is there a compact 2-dimensional subspace which is nowhere dense?

Comment: What do "1-dimensional" and "2-dimensional" mean in this context? That might help.

Comment: One reasonable definition of “two-dimensional” is non-empty interior. But then the question becomes trivial.

Comment: all topological notions of dimension are equivalent in this setting. covering dimension, inductive dimension, etc

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is yes for compact spaces.

Suppose $X\subset \mathbb R^2$ is $2$-dimensional.  Then there exists $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that if $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0$ then $X\cap\partial B(x,\varepsilon)$ is $1$-dimensional (and therefore contains an arc).

Note that for any angles $\alpha<\beta$ the union $$\bigcup_{\varepsilon<\varepsilon_0} \{\partial B(x,\varepsilon):X\cap\partial B(x,\varepsilon)\text{ contains an arc which spans the sector of}\\ B(x,\varepsilon_0) \text{ from angle }\alpha\text{ to }\beta\}$$ is closed by compactness of $X$. By Baire Category  there exist $\alpha<\beta\in \mathbb Q\cap [0,2\pi]$ such that this union contains an open subset of the plane. This means it contains an entire annulus. And hence $X$ contains the given sector of that annulus.